# Verificar si un string es una fecha en PHP

Tags: php, date

Estoy recibiendo dos fechas desde un formulario, estoy en el proceso de validación en el servidor.
Cómo valido el string si es una fecha válida?, hata el momento he descompuesto la fecha en un array  `$fecha_array = explode('-', $fecha);` y he realzado un `count($fecha_array)` para verificar que el `array` tiene 3 datos, y por ultimo verifico que sea una fecha válida con 
`checkdate($fecha_array[0], $fecha_array[1], $fecha_array[2])` el formato usado es `mm-dd-yyyy`. Hasta ahi todo bien el problema surge cuando pruebo con lo siguiente : `01-gg-2019`, ya se que gg no es un día, pero de eso trata la validación. gracias por su ayuda. el error que sale es gg no es integer `checkdate() expects parameter 1 to be integer, string given`

Comment: verifica si es numérico con `is_numeric`de esa manera sabrás si es un numero o no, ya luego de eso continuar con tus validaciones

Comment: Mi estimado eso hice pero a la hora de convertirlo a array la fecha, los fragmentos se convirtieron en string, todos lo detecta como string.

Comment: Eso no tiene mucho sentido, tendrias que ver si no se colo un caracter en el explode, pues si encienrras un valor numerico de esta manera `"21"` y de esta otra `21` igual esa función te devuelve true, pues es un valor numérico, la única forma que devuelva false es con caracteres no numéricos como coma, u otros caracteres porque incluso con guion, espacio, etc, devuelve true, muestra el código de la función que valida para detectar mejor el problema

Comment: Muy bien     `$fecha_entrante = "03-gg-2019";
    $fecha_array = explode('-', $fecha_entrante);
    $fecha_array_cout = count($fecha_array);
    if($fecha_array_cout == 3 ){
        foreach ($fecha_array as $valor) {
            if(!is_int($valor)){
                    echo $valor."no es entero o no es numero <br>";
            }
        }
    }`

Comment: Además necesitarias comprobar que el valor del día está entre 1 y 28-31 en función del mes, el mes entre 1 y 12 y el año en el rango que consideres válido

Answer (score 3):

Una aproximación muy sencilla es comprobar si es una fecha válida en php con date.

```
function check($x) {
    if (date('d-m-Y', strtotime($x)) == $x) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
}
```

Origen aquí https://stackoverflow.com/a/11029851/5675636

Comment: Carmen, para organizar el código que coloques en las preguntas y/o respuestas, selecciona el código y presiona ctrl + k. [Mira esta y otras funcionalidades para formatear lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) también ese mucha ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: @Mauricio Arias Olave gracias por colocarlo, no podía formatearlo desde el móvil

Comment: @Carmen muy buena, salidos

Comment: Gracias @Carmen, esto me ayudo a mi ahora.

Answer (score 2):

Bueno tienes dos maneras de validar la fecha o al menos basado en lo que buscas:

> Cita Editada para validar rangos de la fecha entre 1-31, 1-12 y el rango de año

```
    $fecha_entrante = "mi fecha es 31-02-2019"; 
function validados($fecha){
    preg_match('/(\d{1,2})+(-)+(\d{2})+(-)+(\d{4})/', $fecha, $salida);
    if(count($salida)>=1){
        $salida = array_values(array_diff($salida,['-']));
        if(!in_array($salida[2],range(1,12))){ return false; }
        if(!in_array($salida[3],range(1900,2500))){ return false; }
        if(!in_array($salida[1],range(1,cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, $salida[2], $salida[3])))){ return false; }
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

esto ejecuta el mismo trabajo, pero también te sirve no solo para validar la fecha si no para extraerlas desde un cadena de texto completa.

Espero te sirva. Saludos

Comment: Carlos es una aproximación muy interesante, pero no daría como válida una fecha que por ejemplo sea 99-99-2099?

Comment: @Carmen en eso estamos claros, eso valida es el formato que es lo que el esta haciendo, para determinar no solo el formato si no también la validez de la fecha variarian los parámetros en función de las necesidades de la aplicación.

Comment: Claro, pero la pregunta es cómo valida que sea una fecha válida, de lo cual yo interpreto, puedo equivocarme, que tanto el formato como el dato sean válidos

Comment: @Carmen es solo cuestión de editar y buscar un poco, con las expresiones regulares puedes especificar rangos a validar, he editado mi respuesta para que veas que con las expresiones puedes tanto validar el formato como los rangos válidos por cada valor

Comment: la ventaja de usar las expresiones regulares es que aún así le coloques texto delante o después de la fecha, este la extraerá y podrás validarla, al final es cuestión de usabilidad

Comment: Para validar la fecha uso `checkdate($fecha_array[0], $fecha_array[1], $fecha_array[2])` el problema surge cuando uno de los array no es un número, php muestra error si hay letras o  caracteres especiales `!"#$%&()=` es por eso que antes de pasarlo por la `function checkdate` deseo validarlo que sea números cada caracter. (dd-mm-yyyy)

Comment: @CésarRodríguezReyes ya probaste la función que te dejé? con ella puedes validar eso antes de pasarla a tu función o con ella misma haces todo el trabajo

Comment: @CarlosQuintero funciona de maravilla, gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: @CarlosQuintero el formato puede ser correcto pero la fecha no, `31/02/2019' devolverá 'true' .  [Verificación](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1a3af24fead1df98dc44a1443289df1617051c10). Se podría verificar que la fecha sea correcta para evitar este problema.

Comment: @CarlosQuintero con lo que has añadido mucho más útil, únicamente quedaría comprobar el número de días en función del mes.

Comment: @Carmen listo ya he agregado **cal_days_in_month** el cual nos dirá la cantidad de días de un mes en función del año, así que si le pasamos 31 días a febrero por ejemplo, retornara false.

Comment: @CarlosQuintero +1 por el trabajo, muy buena opción

Answer (score 1):

Tratando de seguir tu idea, me parece debería ser así:

```
$fecha       = '01-rr-2019';
$fecha_array = explode('-', $fecha);
$fechaA      = strtotime($fecha_array[1]."-".$fecha_array[0]."-".$fecha_array[2]);
if($fechaA != "" AND  checkdate(date("m",$fechaA), date("d",$fechaA), date("Y",$fechaA)) === true){
    //coNtinuas tu codigo
    echo "Fecha OK";
}
echo "<br> ".date("Y-m-d",$fechaA);
```

Comment: Adrián, para organizar el código que coloques en las preguntas y/o respuestas, selecciona el código y presiona ctrl + k. [Mira esta y otras funcionalidades para formatear lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/editing-help) también ese mucha ayuda. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio!!